# Flying with recreational cannabis oil in California?

Tags: california, drugs

Can I bring a vape pen containing a cannabis oil cartridge in my carry-on bag on a flight within (departing & arriving) California? I don't have a medical card.

I realize that it is very  likely to be dismissed as a normal e-cig but I'm curious what risks are involved & the potential legal consequences.

I am asking specifically about recreational in California, not medicinal or other states.

Comment: Don't do it. I live in Denver and they're constantly warning us that airports are *federal* territory, and that *federal* laws apply. Cannabis is still illegal at the federal level.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas you should make this an answer, and add a hyperlink to the source of the info.

Comment: @DonPeat This was a recent story from Las Vegas.  If they are doing this, then there is obviously a problem. https://www.cnn.com/2018/02/24/us/vegas-marijuana-box-trnd/index.html

Comment: @DonPeat - It's not TSA you're worried about. It's the patrolling ATF, DEA, drug dogs, and other law enforcement agencies. They do not make you throw it away, they arrest you because possession is illegal. Possession of enough and they hit you with "intent to sell."

Comment: If you want to take the risk, fine. But I've personally been accosted by drug dogs when arriving at Denver International to catch a flight, before even getting to security, because they smelled weed on my shoes.

Comment: It's legal in the state. But the airport is *federal* territory. It's been legal in Colorado since we ratified an amendment to our constitution in '08 but that hasn't stopped *federal* law enforcement. Federal agencies have their own agendas and reasons to do things.

Comment: *It seems like an inordinate waste of time/energy for everyone involved.* This is the War on Drugs we're talking about...

Comment: @DonPeat Federal drug enforcement agencies have literally spent decades arresting people, often going out of the way for small crimes, especially targeting communities of colour. Considering the current climate, it is very common to see federal agencies (especially ICE) acting outside of their jurisdictions, and the DEA doing the same will not be surprising. Some stats here: http://www.drugpolicy.org/issues/race-and-drug-war

Comment: This comment thread might be more for Law.SE.  I don't think it's really a question of "federal territory" or "jurisdiction" - the DEA has the legal authority to enforce federal law everywhere in the US.  They currently *choose* not to prioritize enforcing marijuana laws in those states that have legalized it.  But they are legally free to make whatever exceptions they like - if they want to prioritize enforcement at airports, or for that matter bagel shops or amusement parks, they can.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas the use of the word "territory" is not particularly helpful.  An airport, like every other place in a US state, is subject to both state and federal jurisdiction.

Comment: @phoog - Nomenclature notwithstanding, TSA is a federal agency. I have exited this discussion, however, and it's probably more appropriate for law.SE anyway for the jurisdiction aspect.

Comment: @DonP do you want the question removed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for help with breaking the law. Travel Stack Exchange does not provide assistance with breaking the law.

Answer (score 8):

> [**Transportation Security Administration What Can I Bring?**](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/all-list)
>
> **Electronic Cigarettes and Vaping Devices**
>
> The FAA prohibits these devices in checked bags. Battery-powered E-cigarettes, vaporizers, vape pens, atomizers, and electronic nicotine delivery systems may only be carried in the aircraft cabin (in carry-on baggage or on your person). Check with your airline for additional restrictions. Remove all electronic cigarette and vaping devices from carry-on bags if checked at the gate or planeside.
>
> Carry on bags: **Yes**
>   Checked bags:  **No**
>
> **Medical Marijuana**
>
> Possession of marijuana and cannabis infused products, such as Cannabidiol (CBD) oil, is illegal under federal law. TSA officers are required to report any suspected violations of law, including possession of marijuana and cannabis infused products. TSA’s screening procedures are focused on security and are designed to detect potential threats to aviation and passengers. Accordingly, TSA security officers do not search for marijuana or other illegal drugs, but in the event a substance that appears to be marijuana or a cannabis infused product is observed during security screening, TSA will refer the matter to a law enforcement officer.
>
> Carry on bags: **No**
>   Checked bags:  **No**

Comment: @DonPeat Civilian airports are not generally federal property.  There could be exceptions, but all the airports I know are not.  JFK, for example, is [owned by New York City and leased by the Port Authority of New York and New Jersey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_F._Kennedy_International_Airport).

Comment: @Don Peat, your quote indicates that TSA will refer to a law enforcement officer. "Law enforcement officer" definitionally includes federal cops like ICE, DEA, ATF, etc., whom we know are often around and about in airports. Carrying there sure doesn't seem prudent to me.

Comment: @Don Peat, I would have little risk tolerance for this. Your tolerance may differ.

Comment: @DonPeat, absence of proof isn't evidence (I'm a retired lawyer). If you're comfortable with your reasoning, carry away. You may well sail through w/o difficulty. I'll watch from the sidelines.

Comment: @DonPeat, funny we're both in Santa Cruz.