# As a US citizen traveling to Canada for two weeks, what can I do about necessary prescription drugs?

Tags: usa, canada, drugs

I take a lot of different prescription drugs, which require renewal at different times, or may require new prescriptions.  One of these is a Class III controlled substance.  How do I get new prescriptions or refills in Canada, or should I try to make sure I have all I require before I leave?  My US pharmacy may not be willing to refill early, especially the controlled substance.

Comment: For travel, physicians can write a limited quantity prescription, and some pharmacies will short-fill (where you currently have the prescription), giving you enough for your trip.

Comment: My insurance happily covers three month prescriptions (although they have to go through their preferred mail-order pharmacy). Scheduled meds are a bit harder, but we were able to get a Schedule II medication filled for a two month supply without too much trouble for a long vacation. Talk to your doctor, explain the situation, and chances are they'll be able to help you out.

Answer (score 17):

You likely won't be able to fill the prescriptions in Canada without visiting a Canadian doctor (which will be at your cost, as you're not covered by our public health system) and obtaining new prescriptions.  Mind, some drugs are over-the-counter here and are by prescription in the U.S. (e.g. 222s, which are ASA + codeine).

Ensure you not only have the medications in their original packaging (as received from your pharmacy, that is), but that you have a copy of your doctor's prescription with you as well.  The border agents have the right to inspect that paperwork to determine that the prescriptions are indeed yours.

Usually, if you will be traveling out of the country, you can renew prescriptions early (I have done this myself in the past).  You may need to show your travel plans.  Talk to your pharmacist sooner rather than later.

Comment: US pharmacies keep original paper prescriptions, and many prescriptions these days are transmitted electronically from the prescriber to the pharmacy.  The closest thing a traveler could get to the doctor's prescription is probably the label on the medicine.

Comment: In addition to the labeled container, current US pharmacy practice is to give the patient/customer a separate printout of the RX information. This might be reassuring to uniformed people at international borders.

Comment: @David yes, of course.  I usually throw that away without giving it a second thought.  Perhaps I should stop doing that.

Comment: @phoog, take a  look when you have a chance: on my prescriptions, much of the separate printout looks to me like additional labels. One thinks of repackaging in smaller containers...

Comment: and some drugs are prescription only in Canada while freely available elsewhere. Like diclophenac, which I needed badly during my time in Canada but was unable to get. Luckily I had 10 tablets with me that got me through the two worst days of pain .

Comment: @David do NOT repackage prescription drugs when traveling. ALWAYS bring the original packaging with the original labels. Otherwise you might get in trouble for what looks like possession of a controlled substance without a prescription (even if you did have labels).

Comment: @jwenting you're right that any repackaging increases the chances of difficulty. OTOH, the volume reduction is significant — I'm a light packer — from five medium containers to one small one. I have, in the past, frequently decanted enough meds for a trip, and carried them in a single container. I'm leaving tomorrow for a domestic US trip of three weeks, and the thought of doing it again crosses my mind. Doing this while crossing international borders is indeed riskier.

Comment: @phoog Knowing you're going to travel, it wouldn't be difficult to ask the pharmacy to make you a printed copy of the prescription, or to obtain one from your doctor.  A photocopy is entirely adequate if clear.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not from the US, but Europe, and in a similar situation (several prescription and other meds, including some that may be problematic in some countries).

Just get your doctor and/or pharmacy to get you a refill for the duration of your trip, and for the controlled substances a letter stating that yes, you really were prescribed those and have them for personal use only.

Both doctors, pharmacists, and border agents deal with such situations on a regular basis so it should not be something they're not used to for any of them.

Where you'd have to be careful is when taking OTC meds like Aleve or Voltaren, which might actually be illegal to own without a prescription in some countries (I know Voltaren tablets are prescription only in Canada, Voltaren cream is not, go figure).
Last year a European tourist was arrested and thrown in prison in Egypt for trying to bring a few boxes of Aleve across the border for a sick family member in an Egyptian hotel. They were considered illegal drugs and the traveler arrested for trying to enter the country with controlled substances without a license.
I don't think you'll get into that kind of trouble on your trip as long as you have proper paperwork showing that yes, they're your drugs and on a prescription, but with freely sold stuff from the supermarket it can happen.

Comment: You get that kind of trouble if you are trying to bring in prescribed marijuana (that's what Border Patrol learned me)

Comment: @Jungkook that's not medication, it's an illegal drug. Different laws entirely.

Comment: in some US states it is a legal medicine if prescribed

Comment: @jwenting That wasn't a tourist; it was the wife of someone living in Egypt.  And it wasn't just a few boxes of naproxin; it was some quantity naproxin and 290 tablets of tramadol (a pseudo-opioid).  That is, unless this happened twice recently.

Comment: @jwenting medical marijuana is legally prescribed throughout Canada

Comment: @Jungkook The US is a peculiar place. While some states have legalized cannabis, it is a federally controlled and restricted product, and when you cross the border, you're under U.S. jurisdiction in priority to that of the state you're entering.  On the other hand, Canada is legalizing it federally so importing it (within the constraints the law will allow by then) will be perfectly legal.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie, I'll quibble with "under U.S. jurisdiction in priority." While it's true that U.S. federal law prohibits cannabis and several states allow it, the concept of "jurisdiction" is more correctly viewed as *concurrent*. Very few (if any) locations within the borders of the United States are solely under just federal jurisdiction. Military bases may be one, but civilian airports are subject to both state and federal authority. This doesn't mean the feds or a state will necessarily act or enforce, but only that they can. FWIW, I'm a retired attorney.

Comment: @David I'll concede that point, but that doesn't change the practical effects.  You can fly from Vancouver to Seattle once pot is legal in Canada, but you'll be in legal trouble if you try, even if it's legal in both B.C. and Washington.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie I think we're saying the same thing. This recent thread https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/110752/flying-with-recreational-cannabis-oil-in-california/119337#comment293021_119337 addressed the issue of what might actually happen, and what law enforcement agencies might care to do anything about it. My opinion is that the answer to that question is *we don't know.* I also think a prudent attorney would advise a client that it's never safe to carry into the US, and that there's also risk carrying even within a state that permits possession.

Comment: @David I don't disagree :) It's a bit of a legal quagmire, to be sure.

Comment: @Yakk the arrest was for the naproxen, and "some quantity" I recall as being described in papers here as 5 boxes, making it (due to the quantity of pills per box) 50-100 pills. Which is the amount I would take with me for a 3-4 week trip, given that I regularly use naproxen myself for semi-chronic backpain, and a box of 10, if I need them, lasts only 2 days at most.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie the federal government still holds that the federal law prohibiting canabis overrides state laws legalising it. I don't know how frequently they actually attempt enforcement in states where it's legal, but they'll at least have charges to add if someone commits another federal crime and also has some pot on him.